# Acceder a librerías externas de eclipse agregadas en "Referenced Libraries"

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts, struts2

Tengo un proyecto en Eclipse realizado con Struts2 y el servidor de aplicaciones que utilizo es TomCat, agregué jar externos dando clic derecho al proyecto, properties, y en Java Build Path aparece la opción.

[image: Opción para agregar jars externos]

Quiero acceder a esa jar porque dentro de él tengo unos cuantos recursos que ocupo dentro del proyecto principal **(imagenes, hojas de estilo, códigos de JS, etc)**, el problema es que no se como acceder directamente  al jar, estuve buscando y encontré una pregunta parecida donde se comentaba que el servidor de aplicaciones no sabe acceder a un imagen dentro de un jar, ¿tienen alguna idea?
**NOTA**
Los jar externos se agregan en: *Referenced Libraries*
[image: Referenced Libraries]